# Sudden problem with compiling PDF

Tags: pdftex

I have a problem with compiling PDF, suddenly I received information: `Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.`

I have changed anything so it's interesting surprise. Here is content of log file:

```
2019-04-20 23:56:16,432+0200 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2019-04-20 23:56:28,256+0200 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2019-04-21 00:02:18,032+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:02:18,093+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:02:18,093+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:02:18,094+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:02:18,094+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:02:59,603+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:02:59,684+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:02:59,684+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:02:59,684+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:02:59,684+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:03:24,989+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:03:24,991+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:03:24,992+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:03:24,992+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:03:24,992+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:04:24,466+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:04:24,468+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:04:24,469+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:04:24,469+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:04:24,469+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:04:44,372+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:04:44,375+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:04:44,375+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:04:44,375+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:04:44,375+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:06:31,726+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:06:31,729+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:06:31,729+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:06:31,729+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:06:31,729+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:07:21,093+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:07:21,095+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:07:21,096+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:07:21,096+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:07:21,097+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:08:21,368+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:08:21,371+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:08:21,371+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:08:21,372+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:08:21,372+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:08:44,670+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:08:44,673+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:08:44,674+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:08:44,674+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:08:44,674+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:12:34,296+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:12:34,298+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:12:34,298+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:12:34,299+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:12:34,299+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:15:21,543+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:15:21,545+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:15:21,546+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:15:21,546+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:15:21,546+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:20:06,677+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:20:06,785+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:20:06,785+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:20:06,785+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:20:06,796+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:22:15,065+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:22:15,067+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:22:15,067+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:22:15,067+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:22:15,067+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:23:28,950+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:23:28,953+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:23:28,953+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:23:28,953+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:23:28,953+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:29:16,170+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:29:16,172+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:29:16,173+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:29:16,173+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:29:16,173+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 00:29:40,831+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 00:29:40,831+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 00:29:40,831+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 00:29:40,831+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 00:29:40,831+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 09:09:22,691+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 09:09:22,807+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 09:09:22,807+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 09:09:22,807+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 09:09:22,818+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 17:36:00,085+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 17:36:00,133+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 17:36:00,133+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 17:36:00,133+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 17:36:00,133+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 17:41:31,562+0200 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2019-04-21 17:41:46,039+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 17:41:46,041+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 17:41:46,041+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 17:41:46,042+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 17:41:46,042+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 17:42:51,345+0200 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2019-04-21 17:43:00,289+0200 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2019-04-21 17:43:08,383+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 17:43:08,384+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 17:43:08,385+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 17:43:08,385+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 17:43:08,385+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 17:51:17,222+0200 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2019-04-21 17:51:26,060+0200 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2019-04-21 17:51:33,546+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 17:51:33,548+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 17:51:33,548+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 17:51:33,548+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 17:51:33,548+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
2019-04-21 17:53:32,286+0200 INFO  pdflatex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2019-04-21 17:53:41,170+0200 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2019-04-21 17:55:10,671+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package microtype triggered by tex\latex\microtype\microtype.sty
2019-04-21 17:55:10,672+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Administrative mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.
2019-04-21 17:55:10,673+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-04-21 17:55:10,673+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-04-21 17:55:10,673+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1134
```

I have read somewhere that removing this file may work, but in my situation it didn't work unfortunately. Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: Go to command line and type `pdflatex`. Tell me what happen.

Comment: This is what appeared:This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer *pdflatex Praca_dyplomowa.tex
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `pdflatex'.
<*> pdflatex
             Praca_dyplomowa.tex

Comment: remove the pdflatex in whatever dialog you added it, use only the file name.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you mean that I should remove this file or type only Praca_dyplomowa.tex in command line? If second version, this command isn't recognised

Comment: Now it started to work and is showing similarly: **Praca_dyplomowa.tex
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `Praca_dyplomowa.tex'.
<*> Praca_dyplomowa.tex

Comment: It looks like 2017 MiKTeX (pre console) and updates were triggered so is likely unstable need to check there are not two conflicting versions what is the reply from a console command such as `where /r \ pdfLaTeX` and `where $path:pdflatex` (you can add that to your question) the file you need to delete after a bad run is the ...aux

Comment: @KJO so I should delete the file which will be in  shown directory after typing `where $path:pdflatex`?

Comment: NO that is the one to keep

Comment: Go in the windows explorer to the folder of your tex file. In the address list type `cmd` and hit the enter key, this should open a (black command line) with the problem pointing to the folder. Type there `pdflatex Praca_dyplomowa` and hit enter. Show then a screenshot of what happens (add it to your question). (But first make a backup of your files in case you haven't done it yet.)

Comment: @ KJO After pasting this directory, the console is appearing

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry, but I don't know where exactly I ought to type `cmd`. I have such a problem for a first time and I'm not computer scientist

Comment: Ulrike is asking what the reply is from a command line simply calling pdflatex with your tex filename where it is located that will give her much feedback about current situation, my question is to check what you said about installing updates has not affected the way exe files fuction. Ulrike wants you to navigate to tex folder then where the foldername is at top address bar change it to CMD and enter will open the cmd prompt in the correct place

Comment: In the address line in the windows explorer, where you see the path.

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is the issue solved? How?